# Why are the inputs for my AbstractRNNCell is always None?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I made a CustomCell class to observe how `cell.get_initial_state` works.

```py
class CustomCell(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell):  # (tf.keras.layers.AbstractRNNCell):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial_state(self, inputs, batch_size=None, dtype=None):  # See how initial_state is initialized
        print("\n>> CALLING: get_initial_state")
        print(f"inputs ({type(inputs)}/{id(inputs)}): {inputs}\nbatch_size ({type(batch_size)}/{id(batch_size)}): {batch_size}\ndtype ({type(dtype)}/{id(dtype)}): {dtype}")
        outputs = super().get_initial_state(inputs=inputs, batch_size=batch_size, dtype=dtype)
        print(f"outputs ({type(outputs)}/{id(outputs)}): {outputs}")
        return outputs
        
    def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
        print("\n>> CALLING: call")
        print(f"inputs ({type(inputs)}/{id(inputs)})): {inputs}\nstates ({type(states)}/{id(states)})): {states}")
        outputs = super().call(inputs, states, training=training)
        print(f"outputs ({type(outputs)}/{id(outputs)})): {outputs}")
        return outputs
```

Then, defined an RNN layer using this cell

```py
tf.keras.layers.RNN(CustomCell(embedding_dim), return_sequences=True, zero_output_for_mask=True, return_state=False, stateful=False, unroll=True)
```

I was expecting that the inputs arg would contain the input sequence at inference time, but it always return None as seen in the prints below.

This is a problem for me since I want to initialize the cell based on the input sequence at inference time. Any one have an idea on how to do this? Or any detail that I missed in the code?

```
>> CALLING: get_initial_state
inputs (<class 'NoneType'>/4356090016): None
batch_size (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>/140398757412432): Tensor("custom_model_1/rnn_45/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
dtype (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.dtypes.DType'>/140401518698848): <dtype: 'float32'>
outputs (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>/140398757412336): Tensor("custom_model_1/rnn_45/zeros:0", shape=(None, 200), dtype=float32)

>> CALLING: call
inputs (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>/140398758466832)): Tensor("custom_model_1/rnn_45/unstack:0", shape=(None, 200), dtype=float32)
states (<class 'tuple'>/140398758462080)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/zeros:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>,)
outputs (<class 'tuple'>/140399244202880)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>, [<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>])

>> CALLING: call
inputs (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>/140398758467696)): Tensor("custom_model_1/rnn_45/unstack:1", shape=(None, 200), dtype=float32)
states (<class 'tuple'>/140398758461936)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/SelectV2_1:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>,)
outputs (<class 'tuple'>/140398757201280)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh_1:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>, [<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh_1:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>])

>> CALLING: call
inputs (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>/140398758465488)): Tensor("custom_model_1/rnn_45/unstack:2", shape=(None, 200), dtype=float32)
states (<class 'tuple'>/140398758466160)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/SelectV2_3:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>,)
outputs (<class 'tuple'>/140399234167488)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh_2:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>, [<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh_2:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>])

>> CALLING: call
inputs (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>/140398758467120)): Tensor("custom_model_1/rnn_45/unstack:3", shape=(None, 200), dtype=float32)
states (<class 'tuple'>/140398757409792)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/SelectV2_5:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>,)
outputs (<class 'tuple'>/140398757201280)): (<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh_3:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>, [<tf.Tensor 'custom_model_1/rnn_45/custom_cell_1/Tanh_3:0' shape=(None, 200) dtype=float32>])
```